# Installing CodeIgniter 4 on Amazon AWS Cloud 9 server

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, apache, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

This question is about **CodeIgniter 4**, please do not mark my question as already answered with questions related to CodeIgniter 3. Thank you.

I try to make a fresh install of CodeIgniter 4 on an Amazon AWS EC2 Cloud 9 server.

I encountered some problems.

First, I configured the Apache server on port 8080 as explained on this page : https://lucidar.me/en/aws-cloud9/how-to-...d9-server/

The, I install CodeIgniter 4 with composer and configure it following this instructions: https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide...ith-apache

My first problem is that I do not have a apache2/conf/httpd.conf file. Is it the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf ? Any way, I think the rewrite module is natively enable on my server.

The Apache server works but not CodeIgniter. I got the following errors:

> Warning:
>   require(/home/ubuntu/environment/app/Config/../../vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/bootstrap.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/ubuntu/environment/public/index.php on line 37
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/ubuntu/environment/app/Config/../../vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/bootstrap.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in
>   /home/ubuntu/environment/public/index.php on line 37

I do not have `vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/bootstrap.php` files in the Config folder.

Any idea about what I missed?

Comment: `/var/log/apache` is the default log file location for apache on Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you, I updated the question.

Comment: My guess is you didn't run composer install and hence this error. You have to install packages from composer. (This is not related to apache).